Some users are Authenticating using ADFS server not Azure
I have seen a issue with my current organization where when users are authenticating to O365 or Enterprise Apps in Azure, some users are going to ADFS to authenticate. this is only happening to some users but not everyone. most of the users are getting the MS online sign in page to authenticate.
Can anyone please help me to identify this issue? We have some apps configured via ADFS and that's ok if the users are accessing ADFS apps, but this is happening to everything MS, such as MS online, O365 and also Azure configured SSO Apps going to ADFS sign in page to authenticate.
Thank you!
